# What will I miss with non-100% viewfinders?

Tags: viewfinder

In the [answer to this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24538/how-important-is-the-viewfinder-figures-like-95-100-for-canon-7d/24540#24540), it says:

> Anything less than 100% means that there are elements that will be captured in the scene that you cannot see at the time you look through the viewfinder.

Where exactly will these missing elements and details be located? Are they located at the ends of the viewfinder?

Comment: It's one of those things that don't matter if you don't know what it means, but can't live without once you've had a taste of it.

Comment: Yep--The K-5's 100% viewfinder is far superior to the K-r's 96% viewfinder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're missing is the edges of what will show up in the picture. Exactly how much on which sides is open to question -- typically what you see won't be perfectly centered in the picture.

Comment: However, I've found that if you have an LCD screen you can turn on 'Live View' and see what you're missing in your viewfinder (at least, I can on any Canon Rebel....I would imagine it's true for other manufacturers?)

Comment: @huzzah: Yes -- Live View normally shows 100%, regardless of what the optical viewfinder does/doesn't show.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, *normally* except for Sony DSLRs which only show 90% in Live-View and one long discontinued model from Olympus.