# Is it worth to upgrade from Canon D600 to Nikon 610D in 2020?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I've been holding Canon D600 + Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8 lens (no additional gears at all (i.e. no external lighting etc...)) for 7 years. Here's what I've achieved with this combination: https://www.flickr.com/photos/vdmakwana/

I would like to take my photography to next level with buying a full-frame camera + a decent lens and a couple of other gears.

After performing my research I've settled down on Nikon 610D + 24-120mm f/4 lens + Godox V1.

My main interest of photography is mainly Landscape and Astro with a little bit of Portrait. Do you guys think, with this combination I can perform better than what I'm currently doing?

I do lots of post-production of my photos so a decent Dynamic Range is important than any other features (i.e. articulated screen, bluetooth/wi-fi etc...)

I am fully aware that Nikon 610D is discontinued but the main reason I'm going for it is the price; this way, I can fit the Camera + Lens + External lighting budget under NZD $2500/USD $1700.

Can you guys please advise if I'm making any stupid mistake here? And please recommend any other Camera/gears that would suit my needs.

Comment: Do you mean Canon 600D (not D600)?

Comment: Hi Vishal, can you perhaps edit the question to explain how your current gear is holding you back? What are you missing in your current setup and hope to achieve by going to your proposed set?
It's hard for others to judge for you if "it's worth it", but concrete questions like "Will I gain low light performance if I switch from this setup to the other" is answerable (just an example).

Comment: *I would like to take my photography to next level with buying a full-frame camera*  That is not going to take your photography to a "next level".  Unless it has some very specific technical capability you *need* then your photography is mostly down to your skills.

Comment: Related: [Does the camera matter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101665/1587) and [When should I upgrade my camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71199/15871) and [How much does the Camera Model/Age matter when purchasing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/69437/15871) and [How to improve image sharpness on Canon 700D?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90717/15871)

Comment: We've got a few questions around here already asking whether a "pro" camera from a few years back is "better" than a newer  "entry level" camera. Have you found those helpful at all? Specific product recommendations are off topic here. I would encourage you to [concentrate on improving your skill and knowledge as a photographer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/90776/15871), rather than chasing better images through [GAS](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98948/15871).

Comment: You could also look at the d810 or d800 if you want to switch no Nikon. They are going for very low prices used/refurbished. If you are happy with the lens you have, it may be a good idea to stick with Canon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After performing my research I've settled down on Nikon 610D + 24-120mm f/4 lens + Godox V1.
>
> My main interest of photography is mainly Landscape and Astro with a little bit of Portrait. Do you guys think, with this combination I can perform better than what I'm currently doing?

The 17-70mm you have is 27.2-112mm full frame equivalent.

The f/2.8 you have is f/4.48 full frame equivalent, both in terms of background blur and in terms of light collecting ability. Going to f/4 full frame lens is one-third stop faster. Not by much.

Let's check on a use case basis:

- Landscape: you have slightly better zoom range so picking the right composition will be slightly easier as for landscape shots zooming with your feet is very, very slow indeed. Landscape photography is not typically light limited (unless taking landscape pictures in windy low light conditions)
- Portrait: the 120mm vs 112mm you currently have won't buy you much more versatility. The f/4 you are going to get over the f/4.48-equivalent won't buy you much more background blur or low-light capability
- Astro: the 24mm will be slightly better than 27.2mm if taking wide-angle milky way photographs, but not by much and an f/4 ain't no astro lens.

I would say the kit you're planning to purchase won't be a major benefit. Of course, for full frame it's easier to buy good lenses. If you add a good portrait lens (a fast aperture short tele) and a good astro lens (a fast aperture wide-angle) then you may see benefits from moving to full frame.

But, if you plan to buy just the camera and lens you said you're going to purchase and stop there, it won't be worth the money.

Me? I would buy a 50mm "nifty fifty" and some lighting gear for your current Canon. Much cheaper that way. Unfortunately, good astro lenses for crop Canons are hard to find but the 17-70mm at 17mm and f/2.8 will be a reasonable choice.

Comment: You do not comment on the quality differences of the lenses and sensors, only their specifications. I think the answer could be improved by adding that.